# How to perform String.IsWhiteSpaceOrNull for all text box in my form?

Tags: c#

I have 8 textboxes and all of them should be filled to enable my button, I have already done it with code below in a timer.

```
private void tmrTextChanged_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEnterUsername.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEnterPassword.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtConfirmPassword.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLastName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGender.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTelephone.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMobilePhone.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCity.Text))
            btnCreateAccount.Enabled = true;
    else
        btnCreateAccount.Enabled = false;
}
```

but the condition is so long and what if textboxes were more than this? so i'm trying to write it in another way but button enables before i fill all of them, here is the code.

```
private void tmrTextChanged_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control item in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Text))
            btnCreateAccount.Enabled = true;
        else
            btnCreateAccount.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

it seems that it doesn't check all of them how can i check them all? (windows form)

Comment: Try the Validate event

Comment: You have error in your logic. It will return `Enabled` `true` or `false` depending on last control checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
btnCreateAccount.Enabled = !Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(x=>string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text));
```

This way you check if in the collection of your text boxes is any with it's text null or white space. If so, then we take the negation of the right hand, which would be !true = false. Otherwise the result would be !false =true.

For further documentation on method called `Any`, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: you forgot to add `!`

Comment: tnx, what is x here? could you explain about =>.

Comment: @Riddle, you welcome ! Of course. That's the way we write lambda expressions in C#. That's rather a big topic to be explained in a comment, but I will make a try. The variable that is in the left hand of  => could be regarded as a parameter of a method, the expression on the right hand could be regarded as the result of some calculations that have be done using the parameter x. So you can assume that x is the input and the expression on the right of => is the output. I will try to post a link to have a look further.

Comment: @Riddle please have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx. If you have further questions on this topic, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: seems like nested controls are not taken into account.

Comment: @Christos i have a nested TextBox now (textboxes are in a gropbox), what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

```
btnCreateAccount.Enabled = !Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                    .Select( tb=>tb.Text )
                                    .Any( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace )
```